# How to work with an array that has the same elements multiple times

Tags: javascript

In this code, I have a shopping cart that has album objects in the cart.items array. There are five different album elements all together, however, there are multiple instances of them. I'm trying to display the name of the album, the singer, the quantity of the particular album purchased, and the subtotal for each album. I do not understand the logic on how to get the information I need from the cart.items array. Here is the code

```
    /** Program Description: This program simulates purchases using a 
 * loop. The program creates two classes; an album class, and
 * a cart class. The initial amount of money is $1000.00. The program
 * iterates through all the albums and purchases each one, as
 * long as there is money left. Every time an album gets purchased 
 * the initial amount of money is decremented by the purchase
 * price. Each time an item is purchased, it gets added to the cart.
 * The program then displays all the items purchased in the cart.
 * It should show the album name, artist name, quantity purchased,
 * and sub total for each. It then shows the total purchase price,
 * and the amount of money left over  
 * 
 *  Pseudocode:
 *  
 *      Create a constructor for Album object
 *      Create classes that inherit from Album
 *          Store these classes in an array
 *      Create a constructor for Cart object
 *      Create a const variable for initial money
 *      Loop to simulate purchases
 *          Iterate over an array of albums
 *          Purchase each one as long as there is money left
 *          Decrement money by purchase price
 *          Add item to cart
 *      Display info                                                    **/

// Create a constructor for Album class
function Album(title, artist, price){
    this.title = title;
    this.artist = artist;
    this.price = price;
    this.date = new Date();
    this.quantity = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
};
Album.prototype.purchase = function(){
    this.quantity--;
    if (this.quantity > 0){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return -1;
    }
};
// Create objects that inherit from Album
var pimpAButterfly = new Album("To Pimp a Butterfly", "Kendrick Lamar", 29.99);
pimpAButterfly.tracklisting = ["Wesleys Theory", "For Free", "King Kunta", "Institutionalized", "These Walls"];

var blameItAll = new Album("Blame It All On My Roots", "Garth Brooks", 29.98);
blameItAll.tracklisting = ["Blame It All On My Roots", "Neon Moon", "Papa", "Thunder Rolls"];

var killLights = new Album("Kill the Lights", "Luke Bryan", 20.83);
killLights.tracklisting = ["Kick the Dust Up", "Kill the Lights", "Strip it Down", "Home Alone Tonight"];

var platinum = new Album("Platinum", "Miranda Lambert", 20.61);
platinum.tracklisting = ["Girls", "Platinum", "Little Red Wagon", "Priscilla", "Automatic"];

var painKiller = new Album("PainKiller", "Little Big Town", 24.99);
painKiller.tracklisting = ["Quit Breaking Up With Me", "Day Drinking", "Tumble and Fall", "Painkiller"];

// Store these objects in an array
var albums = [pimpAButterfly, blameItAll, killLights, platinum, painKiller];
// Create a constructor for Cart class
function Cart(val){
    this.items = [];
};

Cart.prototype.add = function(val){
    this.items.push(val);
};

Cart.prototype.remove = function(val){
    this.items.splice(albums.indexOf(val), 1);
};

//Create a constant variable for initial money
var INITIAL_MONEY = 1000.00;

// Create an instance of the Cart object
var cart = new Cart();

// Calculate cheapest album price
var cheapestPrice = albums[0].price;
for (var j = 1; j < albums.length; j++)
    if (albums[j] < cheapestPrice){
        cheapestPrice = albums[j];
    };

// Loop to simulate purchases
var i = 0;
while(INITIAL_MONEY >= cheapestPrice){
    i = 0;
    while(i < albums.length){
        //Purchase each one as long as there is money left
        if (INITIAL_MONEY >= cheapestPrice){
            albums[i].purchase();
            //Decrement money by purchase price
            INITIAL_MONEY = INITIAL_MONEY - albums[i].price;
            //Add item to cart
            cart.add(albums[i]);
        }
        i++;
    }
};


console.log(cart.items);
/**console.log("Album Name\tArtist Name\tQuantity\tSubtotal");
for(var count = 0; count < cart.items.length; count++)**/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through your cart and sum up the information you need, here's some pseudocode:

```
for(var count = 0; count < cart.items.length; count++){
  var item = cart.items[count];
  //item is now an album, now sum up the quantities into a results array, pseudocode:
  results[item] += item.quantity
}

//loop through your results and display all information:

for(var count = 0; count < results.length; count++){
 console.log("Album: "+results[count].title);
 console.log("Artist: "+results[count].artist);
 console.log("Quantity: "+results[count].quantity);
 console.log("Subtotal: "+results[count].price * results[count].quantity);
}
```

edit: This will count the albums in the cart:

```
var counts = {};
cart.items.forEach(function(x) { counts[x.title] = (counts[x.title] || 0)+1; });
console.log(counts);
```

Comment: Let me try that. Don't I have to declare results[item]?

Comment: items.quantity represents how many were in the store to purchase, not how many were purchased. How do I find out how many of the same elements are in the array to get the quantity?

Comment: You just forgot the "topic" => `cart.items.forEach(function(x) { counts[x.title] = (counts[x.title] || 0)+1; });` for a grouping by title

Comment: Thanks, Anonymous0day. Added the title.